# Internet Explorer doesn't adjust for table cell height when using overflow-x:auto (so it hides content). Chrome does. How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

**Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

**Internet Explorer:**

[image: Internet Explorer]
Ok so the top photo is how it should look like. That's on Chrome. The bottom photo is how it looks like on IE11. As you can see, it hides all the content and doesn't adjust vertically for the scroll bar. Is there a way I can fix this? My code for this is basically:

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Note: Sorry, I am not super experienced with stackoverflow and don't know how to separate the pictures. The second picture starts where it says Aimee Reedy - Fredericka McGee - 10/17/16 for the second time.

Comment: Can you provide some of your table code and more of the CSS used on the table or re-create the issue in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wwr1djan/1/

Here is a JSFiddle! It looks different on IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work in both chrome and ie10+:

```css
td {
  text-align:left;
  color:blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:200px;
  overflow-x:auto;
}

th{
  text-align:left;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none)
{
  .padding{overflow-y:hidden;}
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Emma Stone</td>
        <td>Hot Woman</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shia Labeouf</td>
        <td><div class = "padding">
        Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy, Crazy
        </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is you are trying to use a `block` element inside a container that is designed to use a `table-cell`. Like Kashif mentions in his answer you should add a `div` container and then do the `overflow` scroll on that element (which is the cleaner way to accomplish this).

An alternate way to do this would be to change your `td` and `th` elements to use an `inline-block` and `width` properties. The only problem doing it this way is you end up removing the table cell element which kind of defeats the purpose of using a table to begin with.

```
td, th {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:left;
  color:blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
  max-width:200px;
  overflow-x:auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 49%;
}
```

Here is your [fiddle with the code](https://jsfiddle.net/wwr1djan/6/). Sorry its pretty messy I didnt have time to go through and work out the kinks but you should be able to get the idea. hope that helps.